# How to check if array has more than 2 repeating elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, logic

I have an array say `arr[]={8,2,3,6,1,4,5,3,2,2}`
How can I find if my array has more than 2 repeating elements e.g here element `2` is repeating thrice but it should allow it only twice (not more than 2).

Comment: Do you want help to figure out an algorithm, or do you need help with code you already have?

Comment: I want help in algorithm

Comment: What are **YOUR** thougts / ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you need to count elements. But how - depends on element nature.

For small positive ones - just array of counters.

```
Counts[a[i]]++
```

For arbitrary range - map with value and counter

```
if a[i] in map:
   map[a[i]]++  //increase key
else
   map.add(a[i], 1)   //add value with key=1
```

Also you can sort array, then walk through it, counting equal neighbors

```
count = 1 
for i in range(1, len(a))
   if a[i] == a[i-1] 
      count++
      check count
   else
      count = 1
```